# how to display based on a object's key in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In angular, if i have an object such as :

```
[{
  id : 1, 
  subject : BIO, 
  class : '101' , 
  time : 'mon'
 },
 {
  id : 2, 
  subject : BIO, 
  class : '101', 
  time : 'tues' 
 },
 { 
  id : 3, 
  subject : MTH, 
  class : '101-00', 
  time : 'wed'
 },
 {
  id : 4, 
  subject : MTH, 
  class : '101',
  time : 'tues'
 },
 {
  id : 5, 
  subject : BIO, 
  class : '102', 
  time : 'sat' 
 },
```

And I wanted to display all of the results underneath each subject title, is there a directive I can use or something I need to whip up?

Is there way to output based on key value pair by category?

so my output would be

---

### BIO

All class numbers and time.

---

### MTH

All math classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "groupBy" filter from angular-filter library which does exactly what you need:
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

Comment: Agree, is cleaner than having 2 separate blocks... The @Claies response will be helpful when you need a certain order to show the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way to do this would be to use a `filter` over `ng-repeat`.  Something like the following:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.classes = [{
    id: 1,
    subject: 'BIO',
    class: '101',
    time: 'mon'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    subject: 'BIO',
    class: '101',
    time: 'tues'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    subject: 'MTH',
    class: '101-00',
    time: 'wed'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    subject: 'MTH',
    class: '101',
    time: 'tues'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    subject: 'BIO',
    class: '102',
    time: 'sat'
  }, ]
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  BIO:
  <div ng-repeat="class in classes | filter: 'BIO'">
    {{class.subject}} {{class.class}} {{class.time}}
  </div>
  <hr> MTH:
  <div ng-repeat="class in classes | filter: 'MTH'">
    {{class.subject}} {{class.class}} {{class.time}}
  </div>
  <hr> ALL:
  <div ng-repeat="class in classes">
    {{class.subject}} {{class.class}} {{class.time}}
  </div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/AJXZtCHz5ZA51FWIBaXU?p=preview

I added the groupBy filter to the mix to show the difference, from the answer by @DmitryVasiliev

http://plnkr.co/edit/wEEvOfccZ0ipPS14vnD5?p=preview